# Disabling all lock screen notifications

Tags: macos, notifications

How do I disable all notifications from the lock screen on Mavericks? I want to receive notifications while using my computer, but don’t want anything to show publicly when I lock my screen and walk away.

I’ve already gone in to the Notification System Preferences and disabled the “show notification on lock screen” option for every app. But when I install a new app I have to remember to go in there and change that settings, and there are other things built-in to Mavericks that show notifications on the lock screen anyway without any apparent option to hide: the App Store notifying about new updates, a system warning when a USB key is unplugged without ejecting it first, and so on.

How do I globally disable **all** notifications on the lock screen?

Comment: How ridiculous that such an obvious feature is not available.

Answer (score 2):

To disable this you will need to go to the Notifications and uncheck Show notifications on lock screen. There is no global disable, so you will have to do this for each app. To get there:

1. Click the Apple icon in the upper left hand corner
2. Click on System Preferences
3. Click on Notifications
4. Click on the App you don't' want to see notifications from.
5. Under the alert style, uncheck the box for Show Notifications on Lock Screen.

That will removal all the notifications from your lock screen.

Comment: Hi, what is the “Feedbin alert style”? My Notifications preferences screen looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/UUnhRRr.png There is a “Show Notifications on Lock Screen” option under each app, but as described in the question, 1) you need to uncheck this every time there is a new app and 2) things like Finder and the App Store put notifications on the lockscreen but these apps do not show up in Notifications.prefPane.

Comment: I updated the answer. There isn't a way to globally to do this, you will have to do it manually, each app at a time.